# algorithm - Minimum cost intervals covering the points

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to code the following problem:

Given a set `{x1; x2; ... ;xn}` of points on the real line and a set of
closed intervals `[si; fi]` for `1 <= i<= d` where the cost of the i-th interval is `ci > 0`, Find the minimum costly set of closed intervals containing all of the given points.

This is my dynamic programming approach:
Let `dp(i)(j)` denote the cost to cover the first `i` points using the first `j` intervals.

```
dp(i)(j)= inf
    for i=1 to n:
      for j=1 to d:
        if j covers i:  
          dp(i)(j) = min(dp(i)(j), dp(i-1)(j-1)+ Cj)

Return dp(n)(d)
```

I just want to make sure if this is the correct recurrence relation?